# Using Jquery Ajax on JSP to display on Datatables

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, datatables

This is my first time using Jquery Ajax.

The context is that, i'm trying to display more than 10000 rows of data on Datatable, what i did previously was just to use my servlet to forward my Arraylist of data to the JSP, then loop through and display the data onto display data.

It was taking too much to load the datatables. So i decided that i want to try to use Jquery Ajax to see if that will help the issue.

I'm currently facing some issues implementing it, can anyone help me?

I'm using GSON to serialize my arraylist.

**servlet.java**

```
 String json =  gson.toJson(listS);
...

request.setAttribute("listS", json);
request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

**index.jsp**

```
String list =  (String) request.getAttribute("listStartup");
    ......

                    <td>Insert 1st Element</td>
                    <td>Insert 2nd Element</td>

                 <%
               };

    ......


    <script>

    $(function () {
        <% list =  (String) request.getAttribute("listS");%> 
        $("#sp").DataTable({
    "scrollY": 500,
            "scrollX": true,
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax" : list

        });
      });



</script>
```

**My JSONarray is structured like this, this is the output**

```
[
  {
    "Element1": "Text",
    "Element2": "Text",
  },
 {
    "Element1": "Text",
    "Element2": "Text",
  },

....
]
```

If anyone would be kind to link me to some useful documentation that i can read through. I can't seem to find anything that is helpful for me now.

I'm not sure how to iterate through my JSONarray to access the objects and display my JSON data. 
If there are 1000 objects, i will iterate through each object and display their datas in a row.

I also don't know how to make it work with Data tables...

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. This means you cannot mix JSP and JavaScript variables (`"ajax" : list` line is invalid). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678192/how-to-pass-arraylist-from-servlet-to-javascript for hint.

Comment: Hi Jozef, thanks for this, i think i sort of get what you mean.

I think theres quite alot of things i dont get.

So if i'm loading too much data onto data tables. So say if i have 10 pages, when i load the table first, will AJAX load up the first page only? If not how do i make them do it..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting json array where each json object with some specific key (Element1 and Element2). You just need to map those keys with respective columns in datatable. and then pass the list to datatable for rendering.

See below code

```
$(function () {
        var list = <% (String) request.getAttribute("listS");%>;
        //convert string to json object
        var listJson = JSON.parse(list);
       var table = $("#sp").DataTable({
    "scrollY": 500,
            "scrollX": true,
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "columns": [ // map the columns here
             { "data": "Element1" },
             { "data": "Element2" }
             ]
        });

        //render list here
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(listJson); // make sure that list should be json object and not text
        table.draw();
      });
```

Comment: Hi Bhushan, appreciate the quick response, just wanna check real quick if String json =  gson.toJson(listS); is a JSON object. 

Also i don't need these:
"processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax" : list

Comment: Also, i dont think java has "var", how do i overcome this

Comment: you are reading json through request object but also casting it to String hence here we need to parse it to JSON again. We don't need processing, serverside and ajax here as you are already getting list from request object instead of making any extra API call

Comment: var is from javascript and not for JAVA as your datatable script is outside of scriptlets

Comment: okay so i will need to reparse it into a JSON object. Is there anyway for me to parse the json object from servlet to JSP without casting it to string? 

@2nd comment. Got it, i was looking through articles and didn't realise that i can actually use var inside the scripts...

Comment: as you are using scriptlets then you can use same gson libraries to parse string to json object but i would suggest to use JSON.parse only as i have posted in answer instead of importing more java libraries because at the end you need javascript object to pass to datatable

Comment: alright got it, do i need to fix anything on my JSP page though, my data table is now empty and i cant seem to display the data.

Comment: check for any console error on your browser or debug the code using developer console on browser

Comment: Hi Bhushan, it's been awhile, ive been trying to figure it all out but i cant seem to get it to work. I'm not sure how i can test whether the data has been successful parse into JSON. Also, with reference to the guy that commented on my post on top, i'm not sure if it has something to do with fetching the data on server side, and therefore it cannot seem to find my data on client side or something. Would you be able to help?

Comment: you can print the list you are getting from request object in jsp or on logs. Copy that json string and validate it in https://jsonlint.com/ if it is valid JSON string or not. If it is valid then it should definitely get parsed in the javascript inside JSP file.

Comment: Hi Bhushan, i's been awhile again. So the error im facing at the moment, is that on the console w.r.f to your code, the Var "list" is not defined. I checked my JSON, it is valid. So i guess the error is that it is not parsing into javascript?. Right now i just have trouble display JSON data onto data tables.

Comment: can you do one thing, rename `var list = <% (String) request.getAttribute("listS");%>;`  to `var jsonList = <% (String) request.getAttribute("listS");%>;` and put `console.log(jsonList)` to check if this prints value on browser console. Also, rename list to jsonList wherever used in the javascript. This way you can debug if you are getting correct value in jsonList variable

Comment: Hi Bhusan, it's logged undefined

Comment: update, my error is gone when i changed to. var listJson = JSON.parse(<%=listJ%>); but i cant find the logged object on the console either.

Comment: if you are getting undefined then your request object is not passing correct value on JSP, you need to look into server side code

Comment: I've been playing around and trying different things but it cant seem to find the object on my console. I can print the json fine using java but just not when its front end

Comment: if you can reproduce the issue on some weblink which i can access then i can take a look and help you

Comment: Hi Bhushan, i just realised something after posting checkign the source tab, My json is actually pasted within the source. This is the code " var listJson = JSON.parse(<%=listJ%>); "

Comment: the json starts after JSON.parse(*my json is pasted here